# How to disable / enable the play button on a YouTube video with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

**Background:**

I am building a timed jQuery slideshow that contains a YouTube video as one of the elements. I am using the [YouTube JavaScript Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#Playback_status) to detect the play status of a video (slide 1) and pause the slideshow if a video is playing. This portion is working.

However, there is a problem if the user clicks the play button **during the 700ms slide transition**. My jQuery will not detect the playing video on that cycle (slide 1), but it will detect the playing video on the next cycle (showing slide 2). It will pause the slideshow on slide 2, and there is no way to resume the slideshow again - since that would require pausing the YouTube video on slide 1 (now hidden).

**Question:**

How can I disable the play button on the YouTube video during the transition and re-enable it after it is complete? One option is to put a transparent gif image over the entire video, but perhaps there is a more elegant / less kluge-y solution using the [YouTube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html)? I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want to do with the default interface. However, have you taken a look at the [YouTube Chromeless Player](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_player_reference.html)? It's part of the YouTube API, but strips away part or all of the "chrome" on YouTube. My only concern is that this might remove too much of that chrome. Give it a look and see if it will work for you.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that is another problem though if it strips away all the default controls.

Comment: @Mike - Yeah, I haven't used it myself, but a friend of mine had, so I don't know exactly how much control it gives you over what it strips away. But, hopefully this gives you something new to try.